# Does order matter when casting a cantrip with a casting time of a bonus action and another spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting, cantrips, bonus-action

When casting a spell as a bonus action, you can't cast another spell on the same turn except a 1-action cantrip - can the order be "reversed"? Can you cast a cantrip first as a bonus action, then any other spell? If not, would it be broken to allow it?

I'm thinking a Sorcerer casting a Quickened *true strike*, then casting a leveled spell requiring a touch attack. Seems like a great use of the cantrip + Metamagic feature, but it seems like it is not allowed.

Comment: *You extend your hand and point a finger at a target in range. Your magic grants you a brief insight into the target’s defenses. **On your next turn**, you gain advantage on your first attack roll against the target, provided that this spell hasn’t ended.* [It could be a good combo, but *true strike* is useless most of the time.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/51266/40039)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, the order doesn't matter

You cannot cast another leveled spell if you've cast a bonus action spell, and you can't cast a bonus action spell if you've already cast a leveled spell with your action.

> "You can't cast another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of one action" (PHB 202)

That precludes *both* before or after the action spell.

Comment: Also, just realised this Sorc 'trick' wouldn't work, because True Strike states that you gain the effect during your next turn. Bummer--clearly they did not want this to happen.

Comment: I had a small follow-up--if you cast a L>1 spell with your action, can you then cast a cantrip with Quickened Spell as a bonus action?

Comment: @Khashir No. You'd have to be able to cast a spell as a bonus action, and you can't do that if you've already cast one as an action.

Comment: Thank you. So, Quickened Hold Monster, then Shocking Grasp is OK, but not the other way around? To be honest, I don't remember why this came up... Long week, I guess.

Comment: @Khashir exactly. I have no reason why though.

Comment: Now I remember--I wanted to Heighten Hold Monster, then Quicken Shocking Grasp (so that I could attack with advantage and auto-crit on the same turn). Apparently a no-go </3

Comment: Could you address these bits about order in the answer? The comments seem to contradict the answer, so I think crafting it into a coherent whole would improve clarity.

Answer (score 9):

## The restriction applies regardless of the order

The rule on [bonus-action spells](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#BonusAction) states:

> You must use a bonus action on your turn to cast the spell, provided that you haven't already taken a bonus action this turn. You can’t cast another spell **during the same turn**, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action.

No matter when the bonus action spell is cast, you cannot have cast another spell except for a cantrip with a casting time of one action *for the entire turn*. This turn-based stipulation does indeed mean the restriction applies retroactively. It doesn't matter what order - as long as the two spells are cast (or attempted to be cast) on the same turn, the restriction applies.

[Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/693162514704543744) has also clarified and agrees with this:

> **Q:** How do bonus action spell rules go when a noncantrip is cast as a single action then a bonus action spell?
>
> **JC:** If you cast a spell of 1st-level or higher with 1 action, you can't then cast a bonus action spell.

Note that things can get confusing when applying this rule and [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/133767/42386) has a nice table showing all the legal and illegal combinations.