# Does the material component of Booming blade need to be the same one used in the attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cantrips, spell-components

Does the spell specify that the material component need be the same as the one used in the attack?

> As part of [recent errata](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SCAG-Errata.pdf) to the *green-flame blade* and *booming blade* cantrips, their material components have been amended to "a melee weapon worth at least 1 sp" (Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide, 142).

If the attacking weapon and material component do not have to be the same, then can you use a separate weapon (for instance a Pact weapon or a Psychic Blade) for the component?

Comment: When would you want to use one weapon for the component and a *different* weapon for the attack?

Comment: @Medix2 This could be an example: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177347/42386

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### The material component weapon *must* be used to make the attack

The spell states (emphasis mine):

> You brandish **the weapon used in the spell’s casting** and make a melee attack **with it** against one creature within 5 feet of you. [...]

The only weapon used in the spell's casting is the material component; no other weapons is required in order to cast the spell. If they wanted it to be any weapon, they would have worded the spell differently.

Answer (score 7):

### Yes.

The spell specifically says:

> You brandish the weapon used in the spell’s casting and make a melee attack with it against one creature within 5 feet of you.

The “weapon used in the spell’s casting” refers to the weapon used as a material component.