# Would it be balanced to introduce an "Aim Action" that uses the same mechanics as True Strike?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, balance, actions, homebrew-review

There are few things in D&D 5E on which the consensus is as overwhelming as on the fact that [True Strike](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-strike) is an extremely poor cantrip. As discussed in many places, the main problem is the action economy. As [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/175474/55742) to a similar question puts it, casting True Strike is not so much a benefit as it is a trade off: You waste your action on one turn in order to gain advantage and thus use your action more effectively on your next turn. As has also been pointed out countless times, this is rarely optimal, as attacking twice without advantage still has the chance of hitting twice while the chance of hitting at least once is the same as when attacking once with advantage.

The generic scenario in which True Strike actually helps is when a character needs to put all their focus into making sure that one crucial, strategically relevant attack actually hits. Putting it like that doesn't let it sound particularly magical: the character just takes their time to aim. I really like the narrative and I could imagine very dramatic, epic, and satisfying game moments with this mechanic. However, they do not happen, since they alone are hardly a convincing reason to choose the otherwise almost useless True Strike as one of one's limited cantrips.

**Would it be balanced to remove True Strike from the game entirely and introduce an Aim Action that is available to everyone and does exactly what True Strike does (mechanically)?**

Because this Aim Action is a trade off that is suboptimal most of the time, I would consider it balanced for my game, unless one of the following questions has a positive answer:

**Would it step on anyone's toes by making certain class features or spells (other than True Strike of course) obsolete? Are there any exploits in other scenarios than the one described above that I am overlooking?**

---

A sidenote: I also noticed that the [Unearthed Arcana Class Feature Variants](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/class-feature-variants) include the "Cunning Action: Aim" for the rogue.

> You gain an additional way to use your Cunning
> Action: carefully aiming your next attack. As a
> bonus action, you give yourself advantage on
> your next attack roll on the current turn. You can
> use this bonus action only if you haven’t moved
> during this turn, and after you use the bonus
> action, your speed is 0 until the end of the
> current turn.

Having a general Aim Action and allowing this feature variant would keep in line with the idea that the Cunning Action lets the rogue do things anyone can do, just quicker. Of course, one could say that 1.) it's Unearthed Arcana, so it's not a reference for balance, and 2.) the relation between Aim and Cunning Action: Aim is not as simple as with the uses of the Cunning Action from the PHB, but I still thought this observation could be worth mentioning.

Answer (score 13):

## You don't need to do this, because everyone can already do this

The GM is supposed to confer advantage/disadvantage rather than apply modifiers whenever circumstances are altered to give one combatant an edge over another:

> The GM can also decide that circumstances influence a roll in one direction or the other and grant advantage or impose disadvantage as a result.

(also c.f. [this forum post](https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/dungeons-dragons-discussion/rules-game-mechanics/18532-when-to-use-modifiers-vs-dis-advantage))

Having taken a round to line up a shot should *definitely* count as circumstances beneficial to the attacker (that's literally why people aim), so the attacker should already be being given advantage without any house-ruling necessary.

This isn't unbalanced, either: the 'Help' action already lets anyone (or their pet mouse) grant advantage with an action on most things, including attack rolls on targets within 5 feet, and circumstances where an action's worth of work *can't* modify circumstances in some other way sufficient to grant advantage are extremely rare.  Trading an action for advantage is pretty much going to be possible all the time anyways, so letting people do it via 'aiming' really isn't a problem.

Comment: So you're saying it shouldn't even need concentration? And that therefore by RAW True Strike is worse than something you should be able to do anyway?

Comment: @MarsPlastic Yes

Comment: I would tend to disagree on one detail. If only because allowing this invalidate True Strike. Most other action (accept Help) would require either a check (such as what Jon proposes below) or some interaction witht the environment (such  as leading the target in dificult terrain or hiding among the scenery)

Comment: Let me rephrase that. An action seem to me like enough of a cost in term of action economy. But most other options require 'something', either positionning, being aware of the environment or a check of some sort to get in position to attack. For this reason, I feel like the assertion that you can already do it is just false

Comment: This answer is saying "every GM should allow this homebrew Action because it's implicitly obvious it should work".  If that's true, then why isn't it in the basic rules? Agreed with @3C273.  IMO, only the last paragraph really tries to answer the question about whether this homebrew rule is balanced.  (And I do agree, good point about having someone else spend their action to do the same thing, but that generally requires them to be in melee to Help.)  OTOH to justify the status quo, there's a limit to how long you can spend lining up a shot on a moving target before you plateau on accuracy.

Comment: @PeterCordes It's not a homebrew Action, because that's not how the game works.  Players describe what they are doing and negotiate that and the mechanical representation thereof with the GM.  GMs do not, generally, 'allow' actions, they interpret and resolve them.  If a player says "I line up a shot on the orc.  I'm taking extra time to aim because it's important I don't miss" the GM is responsible for modelling that.  Saying "Sorry, there's no 'aim' action in 5e" is both grossly misleading-- 5e doesn't enumerate actions that way-- and a dereliction of GMing duties.

Comment: @PeterCordes that's not to say, of course, that the only way to model such a statement is advantage on the next attack-- *disadvantage* on the attack, rolled immediately, but with misses meaning the player didn't fire rather than fired and missed, or taking an Action to make misses next round be shots the player didn't take rather than fired and missed would also be idiomatic.  But in this case, the player wants advantage and is basically saying "I take an Action to create/wait for circumstances granting me advantage". The rules are clear on what the GM is supposed to do when players do that.

Comment: You're right, 5e doesn't try to enumerate everything players can do.  Let me rephrase, you're saying it's implicitly obvious that GMs should allow it to work *this way* when a player tries to line up their attack or spell. But that's exactly the point of the question.  That ruling would effectively be creating an Aim action, and the question is whether that's balanced.  e.g. it allows a rogue cornered on their own with nowhere to hide to get Sneak Attack every other turn, potentially huge for a high-level rogue.  Is that reasonable?  I don't know.  Should this "aiming" concept work for spells?

Answer (score 3):

## Yes, but it would need a higher cost than one action

5e is pretty heavily based on building advantage in different ways, and the trade off to gaining that advantage. There are two examples of advantage and there costs that I feel relevant, and I think we can find an appropriate cost between them:

- True Strike (*PHB p.284*): the current costs for true strike are: A cantrip slot used for this spell, an action, and concentration.  This spell can only be cast on a target  within 30 feet of  the caster.

This is pretty well agreed upon as being too high of a cost for a single advantage on one attack roll (thus you posing this question). This might work for an Aim action, however, as that would take away the cantrip slot use. Making this action available for all creatures would probably require one more thing to  balance this action out.

- Shoving a Creature Prone (*PHB p.195*): Using the Attack action, you can make a Special melee Attack to shove a creature, either to knock it prone or push it away from you. If you’re able to make multiple attacks with the Attack action, this Attack replaces one of them.
  The target must be no more than one size larger than you and must be within your reach. Instead of Making an Attack roll, **you make a Strength (Athletics) check contested by the target’s Strength (Athletics) or Dexterity (Acrobatics) check** (the target chooses the ability to use). If you win the contest, you either knock the target prone or push it 5 feet away from you.

What  I would think is relevant for an Aim action would be the contested roll.  Probably the Aimer's Insight (Wisdom) against the target's Deception (Charisma).  Combining the relevant parts  of these two methods of gaining advantage, I've come to this result:

### Aim

*You take a moment  to study a creature, taking care to line up your next attack. As an action, choose a target within 30 feet. Make an contested Insight (Wisdom) check against the targets Deception (Charisma). If you win the contest, your next attack roll before the end of your next turn is made with advantage against the target.  You must maintain  concentration on aiming, as though concentrating on a spell.*

Comment: This is a nice idea. It would make the Aim Action **a lot** less reliable, though. I'm a bit worried that it could make it so weak that we're back to an option noone uses anyway.

Comment: @MarsPlastic I think that's a bit what I was aiming for.  Dodge, Disengage, Hide, and Help are all very infrequently used (in the campaigns I play, at least) because they are very situational, and Aim should be as well.

Comment: Yes, keeping it situational is very much what I would like. But isn't it a bit discouraging that even in these rare situations, the odds are still that bad? The comparison with shoving a creature prone might not be appropriate, since everybody gets advantage in melee against a prone creature, possibly even multiple times. Only you benefit from the Aim Action and only for one attack.

Comment: With Shoving though your odds of still having advantage on your next turn are low, as the creature would have had  there turn in  the order (excluding magic shenanigans of some sort) before yours, and could stand up.

Comment: Yes, but you (if you have extra attack) and others might attack a prone creature multiple times with advantage, even it gets up on it's very next turn. As it is right now, the Aim Action is strictly weaker than shoving a creature prone (actually quite a lot weaker).

Comment: Would the help action be a  better comparison? in this case the trade off is that you can't control who gains the advantage; as in if you want to give the rogue advantage for his sneak attack, whoever is in the turn order before the rogue could take your advantage before the rogue has an opportunity, or they have to choose another target before the rogues  turn

Comment: You're right, the Help Action is a good comparison. Seeing that Aim would also need concentration, isn't that an appropriate additional cost in view of the benefits in comparison to Help? On the other hand, Aim has also the benefit of working from a distance...

Comment: @JonAristotle Prone has got a lot of other useful stuff (they can't move or attack very well until they stand up), so help or Dodge might be a better comparison than shove.

Comment: Are you basing the contested checks on Rogue (Inquisitive)'s level 3 feature Insightful Fighting?  It uses the same stats, Wis (Insight) contested by Cha (Deception).  On success, the rogue gains sneak attack even without adjacent allies.  (But it doesn't grant advantage).  It's a weird choice of skills for the general case of anyone doing it, but I guess something other than your usual attack and defense stats make sense if you're trying to spend longer than ~6 seconds aiming.  I would have thought Dex (Deception) or Dex (Acrobatics) might make more sense, though.

Comment: "Aim" seems like a misnomer for this, given that it has a maximum 30-foot range and . Most of what comes to mind when I think about people aiming involves longer ranges,  How does it work if the target's an object?

Comment: @notovny When attacking an object you should generally already have advantage, because the object can't see you.

Comment: I’m also not sure about the shove comparison; that’s a roll to see if you succeed on an action which then happens or doesn’t. A roll for aiming is a roll to see if you grant a bonus on the next roll you make. In any case, in my experience shove is rarely used to knock someone prone, but often used to try and push someone off a cliff or into a hazard and therefore possibly out of a combat entirely. Of course it can also be used to knock someone prone, but this versatility gives it considerably more utility than granting advantage on a single attack.