# Can you cast a bonus-action-spell as a bonus action AFTER casting a action-spell/cantrip as an action?

Tags: dnd-5e, cantrips, bonus-action

From the Player's Handbook (p. 202) under `Casting Time > Bonus Action`,

> *A spell cast with a bonus action is especially swift. You must use a bonus action on your turn, provided that you haven't already taken a bonus action this turn. You can't cast another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of one action.*

meaning that once a bonus-action-spell is cast, following that one cannot cannot cast another non-cantrip spell as an action. However, the wording above does not seem to preclude the use of a non-cantrip spell as an action *BEFORE* using your bonus action to cast a bonus-action spell.

Is there anywhere else in the PHB where it is clarified whether the order matters or not? In the absence of further ruling, should we accept the literal meaning above which says *"cannot cast a non-cantrip spell AFTER a bonus-action spell"*?

Comment: Hi, welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] and visit our [help] for more guidance. I believe the answers to the question "[Does order matter when casting a cantrip with a casting time of a bonus action and another spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47421/does-order-matter-when-casting-a-cantrip-with-a-casting-time-of-a-bonus-action-a)" might answer this question. If this does not answer your question, please let us know via comments or by editing the question to explain why your question is different. Thanks!